# React (add-on) Tab absent in Firefox -> webIDE -> developer tools

Tags: reactjs, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-os, firefox-developer-tools

I have my react app in kaiOS based device. I have webide running the app on my device. I want to be able to debug the app and see the react states/props just like a normal react app running in chrome/Firefox browser environment.

Issue is: 
I don't see the React Tab on developer tools of webIDE window.

(I have the react developer tools addon installed on Firefox)